# How do I use a bearer authorization token in a Azure Scheduler job?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-web-app-service, bearer-token, azure-scheduler

I want to create a scheduler job in Azure where i will perform a GET request of a URL with an authorization header with a bearer token but I cant get it to work. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617000/using-a-bearer-token-for-authentication%E2%89%A0-authorization) similar problem but it's not applicable for my issue.

Today its a button which calls a URL with the header *authorization: Bearer abcdefgh* so how what do i put in the header field in azure scheduler jobs?

Im completely new to this so please guide me in the right direction if i missed something important. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question i just added a header in Action Settings of the scheduler job with *Authorization* as name and *abcdfgh* as value and the job completed perfectly!